# different time results with Locale

Tags: java, android, date, locale, hour

```
    SimpleDateFormat formato =new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String fecha11 = String.valueOf(formato.format(cal.getTime()));

    Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss", locale);
    String fecha22 = String.valueOf(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Results:
14:06:12 (same that hour in my device)
14:16:55 (with Locale("es", "ES"))

And yes, i am in Spain (Bcn) ¬¬' somebody would explain me why??
And next question, is it happen when i change Locale to others countries?

Thanks,

Àlex

Comment: your result don't make sense. MM cannot give numbers larger than 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss", locale);`, you are using `MM` instead of `mm`, so it is the month number instead of the minutes that gets printed (is should be 05 for May though).

Answer (score 1):

mm is minutes. MM is month

your second format is Hour:**Month**:Seconds

*edited after assylias comment*

Comment: It's the way round: MM is month and mm is minute.

Comment: agreed. i based the assumption on the results given. 06 seemed a more logical month as 16.